# Not receving continous frame from opencv

Tags: python, opencv

my function did not return continuous frame ,it return only signal frame and then break
here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
def video():
    cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while cam.isOpened:
        _,frame=cam.read()
        return frame

im=video()
cv2.imshow("image",im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I want such function ,when i call this function ,anywhere in my code it return a continues frame and i do stuff on it whatever display ,face detection or other stuff

Comment: I suppose you know you have put a return statement ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to gather the frames in a while loop without breaking it by returning:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

def video(cam):     
    _,frame=cam.read()
    return frame

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cam.isOpened:
    im=video(cam)
    cv2.imshow("image",im)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: but sir i want these whole code in a single function and whenever i call this function it return only frames

Comment: Than, no offence, learn python basics first. You can not (AFAIK in no language) return in a while loop and expect the while loop to continue.

Answer (score 0):

When you `return`, you just exit the while loop, so it just shows 1 image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cam.isOpened:
    _,frame=cam.read()

    cv2.imshow("image",frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF 
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: but i want this in a function,so whenever i call this function it return me frames and i display these frame anywhere in my code

Comment: Answer below by @Mailerdaimon is what you want